# Default key-binding to clear the command line

Tags: command-line, unix, key-binding, midnight-commander

What is the default keybinding under Midnight Commander for clearing the command line at the bottom ? ( not the one you get with Ctrl-O, but the one-line prompt )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Ctrl-w` works if you are at the end of the line.  Otherwise you need `Ctrl-k` too.

Comment: this is a little bit weird, but seems "expected behaviour": https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/357

Answer (score 8):

According to the [manual](http://www.chm.tu-dresden.de/edv/mc/mc4.5/manual1.html#11) this is `C-a C-k` where:

C-a : puts the cursor at the beginning of line
C-k : kills the text from the cursor to the end of the line.

Comment: This answer is a better way to clean the command line at once

Answer (score 2):

Analog to harrymc's answer, which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to jump to the beginning and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to clear from cursor to line end, you may also use:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to jump to the *end* and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to clear from start to the cursor.